# ios 8: Bundle path changes

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an iOS app that stores the absolute path of files in a database and in generated html documents. I just recently updated my iPhone to iOS 8 and now when ever I run the app it seems that the app is installed in a different directory every re-compile. For example on the first build/run [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] returns something different on the next build/run. What is going on? Is this a new feature of Apple?

Update: A bug report was created

Code example:

If I run the following line over multiple build/runs then I will get a different result each time.

```
#define kOLD_PATH @"oldPath"
NSString* newPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString* oldPath = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kOLD_PATH];

NSLog(@"New Path: %@", newPath);
NSLog(@"Old Path: %@", oldPath);
NSLog(@"Result: %@", [oldPath isEqualToString:newPath] ? @"Same" : @"Changed");

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:newPath forKey:kOLD_PATH];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

The output looks like this over multiple runs

```
New Path: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4FFCE2CB-580D-409A-90CB-EF2B8A1FB653/Library
Old Path: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B038B2DA-F85D-4E18-A5F1-8635834EC454/Library
Result: Changed
```

**Full Disclosure:** In my app the user imports a web page (ePub) that has resources. The resources are stored with the web page. The web page also accesses resources that are part of the app bundle. To achieve this when I load the web page the base url is set to the directory the web page is in and the bundle resources are accessed via absolute file paths. Now that file paths change on every update this is broken. I tried creating symbolic links to the bundle resources but that also fails un subsequent updates.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Refer Technical Note 2406 by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2406/_index.html)

**The breaking change is**

> Beginning in iOS 8, the Documents and Library directories are no
> longer siblings of your application's bundle.

Don't store full path/URL to your documents. Store the file name and always generate full path/URL with recommended approach.

Get the DocumentsDirectory URL

```
// Returns the URL to the application's Documents directory.
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
{
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}
```

Then you get path out of url and append the file name to generate full path.

Comment: even this returns me different paths, each time I run :\

Answer (score 18):

In iOS 8, The file system layout of app containers has changed. Applications and their content are no longer stored in one root directory.

From the iOS 8 Release Notes:

> The file system layout of app containers has changed on disk. Rather
>   than relying on hard-coded directory structure, use the
>   [`NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains) function or the
>   [`URLForDirectory:inDomain:appropriateForURL:create:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/URLForDirectory:inDomain:appropriateForURL:create:error:) method of the
>   [`NSFileManager`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSFileManager) class. See [Accessing Files and Directories](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/AccessingFilesandDirectories/AccessingFilesandDirectories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH3) in [File
>   System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672).

This is not a bug. Make sure you use the recommended APIs (from the above quote) and you won't have a problem.

So, If you are trying to access a bundled resource you added to the project, you would use:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"resourceName" ofType:@"extension"];
```

But if you want to use something that you put in the documents directory, you would use:

```
[[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"resourceName.extension"];
```

Comment: In my app I generate html pages that have hard coded file paths in them. These paths are constantly changing now. I am not sure how I am supposed to handle this.

Comment: Not really. The reason why I have absolute paths in the generated html's is because the scripts I am using are not located in the base URL. The html's depend on user generated content (css, images and so on) and copying the scripts into each html's base path seems bad. So the scripts in html reference the file absolutely. However now that path changes every update.

Comment: I added a full disclosure section to the question so you can really see the exact problem I am having.

Comment: I can go upto iPhone Simulator path in my mac, there i cant able to see iOS 8. How to i get iOS 8 path?.

Comment: @liamnichols I'm seeing NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory change from run to run.  If I save a file in NSDocumentDirectory in one run and try to read it on the next run, it isn't found.  Is that expected?

Comment: @danh: something isn't right there, doesn't seem related to this question though so i would open up a new question on SO if you've already searched and can't find anything.

Answer (score 3):

don't know if you solved your problem, but this link is possible the answer.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/AccessingFilesandDirectories/AccessingFilesandDirectories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH3-SW10

Locating Files Using Bookmarks

A few lines before this section in the page is this text:

"Important: Although they are safe to use while your app is running, file reference URLs are not safe to store and reuse between launches of your app because a file’s ID may change if the system is rebooted. If you want to store the location of a file persistently between launches of your app, create a bookmark as described in Locating Files Using Bookmarks."

Good bye.

Comment: It does work. You can use the guide lines to create a bookmark for the file, then you change the bookmark that is a NSData to a NSString using de encode Base64 and you can store that string to store the location of your file. When you want to read the File you decode the NSString  to the NSData bookmark and then to the URL of the current location of the file.

Answer (score 2):

I think the different path for each build and run is the intended way of things happening in iOS simulator. It is not an issue.

/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4FFCE2CB-580D-409A-90CB-EF2B8A1FB653/Library
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B038B2DA-F85D-4E18-A5F1-8635834EC454/Library

I found even if you use the recommended way

```
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSLibraryDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}
```

The results are same. Different path for each build & run.

Comment: I've experiencing the same behavior, but on the device and not just the simulator.  Used to be that the absolute path of the app would change only upon upgrade (which was really install new version, migrate data, delete original).  I see that the full path changes each time the app runs.