# Bundle path changes with mono touch

Tags: ios, mono, xamarin.ios

Reading up on [ios 8: Bundle path changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25884382/ios-8-bundle-path-changes), it looks that I will need to alter my app so all graphics are in the Resources directory.

The app is using `FromFile` to access files in the app and this works ok. When I move the entire graphics directory to resources and try to use `FromFile`, the app crashes saying the file cannot be found.

I've used a number of different ways to get to the file, but I always get a crash (mainly as there are quite a few different pages all saying different things!).

Currently, I'm using

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(scrlView.Frame.Size);
UIImage.FromResource(assembly, "Resources/Graphics/Backdrop/Backdrop35PC.png").Draw(scrlView.Bounds);
var img = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphics.EndImageContext();
scrlView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromPatternImage(img);
```

For the path, I've tried omitting `Resources/`, changing the `/` to a `.` and any number of other different ways to try and not get a crash.

Is there a definitive way to use `FromResource`? I've tried not using `assembly`, but use `null` instead. Again though, this just crashed.

Answer (score 0):

`FromResource` is for loading bitmap from *classical* .NET/Windows `.res` files than are embedded in your assemblies (e.g. `.dll`). IOW if the file exists inside your **application** bundle (and not inside your assemblies) then you're using the wrong API.

In such cases you should be using `FromFile` and make sure your path is correct as, like you noted, iOS* changed some paths. That was fixed in [XI 8.4.0.27+](http://developer.xamarin.com/releases/ios/xamarin.ios_8/xamarin.ios_8.4/) so you can resume using `Environment.GetFolderPath` like before.

For earlier versions you can use the code provided in the "[Working With The File System](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_the_file_system/)" article.

```
var documents = NSFileManager.DefaultManager.GetUrls (NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomain.User) [0];
```