# Which is the best way to get Document directory path in iOS8

Tags: objective-c, ios8, nsdocumentdirectory

The usual way of getting App Document Directory path is given below.

**Option (1)**

```
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentDirectory {
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, true);
  NSString *documentPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
  NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:documentPath];
}
```

But [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2406/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014932) suggest to use the following in iOS8:

**Option (2)**

```
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory    
                                                   inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}
```

In both ways I am getting the same value.

So there is confusion here. whether I should use the second option or not? is it a mandatory change in iOS 8?

Kindly give your suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I think second option should be better , read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25885321/3800154