# UIImage failed to be loaded for IOS 7.x SPECIFIC

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I was trying to load image using method:

1. `[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]`
2. `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath]`

In IOS 8.x, the images are loaded. However in IOS 7.x simulators, the above methods always return nil. This situation happened in both simulators and devices.

```
NSBundle *myBundle = [NSBundle findMyBundle];
[myBundle load];
NSString *imagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [myBundle bundlePath], imageName];
UIImage *targetImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];

NSLog(@"FrameworkBundle: %@", myBundle);
// Bundle does exist For IOS 7.x
NSLog(@"Image: %@", targetImage);
// targetImage = nil for IOS 7.x; while it does return image for IOS 8.x
```

Is there any method need to notice for loading UIImage about IOS 7.x devices / simulators.?

**Edit:**

Here is what worked out for me:

```
// I have to specify imageType to be @"png"
// If one compose the path without the fileType ending, it does not load the image properly.
NSString *imagePath = [myBundle pathForResource:imageName ofType:@"png"];
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
```

Comment: Please read the question carefully, the bundle does exist.

Comment: OK, I see. But there are no embedded frameworks in iOS 7 are there? Could that have something to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

I think there was a change when iOS 8 launched in how and where the bundles exist, I just search on Stackoverflow and probably this question (and its answer can help you), you probably have to use a different loading method for locating bundle or resource

[ios 8: Bundle path changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25884382/ios-8-bundle-path-changes)

PS:should have been a comment in your answer but dont have enought reputation at the moment :)

Comment: Thank you. This is a working solution, I updated the question with my approach. I will wait a bit before accepting your answer, if no UIImage method could be applied here.