# How to save image after selecting from UIImagepickercontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm building an iOS app using Swift and Xcode 6. I have implemented the functionality to pick image from UIImagePickerController and set into UIImageView.

Here is my to code select image from UIImagePickerController:

```
@IBAction func loadImageButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
        // imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera
        //imagePicker.sourceType = .SavedPhotosAlbum

        presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    // MARK: - UIImagePickerControllerDelegate Methods
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
           // imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
            imageView.image = pickedImage

        }

        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Now i'm finding a best way to store this image and when user come again in the app, i can get the image and display in the uiimageview.

Could some help me how can i implement this.

Help is appreciated!

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
let imageData: NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(yourImage, 0.9)
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
let destinationPath = documentsPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("filename.jpg")
imageData.writeToFile(destinationPath, atomically: false)
```

Then later to retrieve the image:

```
let loadedImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: destinationPath)
```

Comment: could you please explain me what will be the destinationPath when i have to get the uiimage in viewDidLoad.let loadedImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: destinationPath)

Comment: You can just do the same thing to get the destination path as you did when saving the image. i.e `let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String... etc`

Comment: This is the easiest way to do it. If you wanted a more comprehensive way you should think of Core Data. That requires more set up.

Comment: Do you know about some tutorial regarding Core Data to save image.

Comment: I wouldn't use core data if all you wanted to do is just save images. I would stick to using the fileManager. What concerns do you have with using the file manager as show above?

Comment: here is  a core data tutorial if your interested. http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started

Comment: No there is no concern i was just asking that if you know about that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83722/discussion-between-villy393-and-daljeet).

Comment: Starting in iOS 8 the file path changes between launches. See this answer for details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25884382/ios-8-bundle-path-changes