# dataWithContentsOfFile return null

Tags: ios, nsdata

```
NSString *path = dict[@"fileURL"];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

imageData is null

```
dict[@"fileURL"] =
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/0906AB53-CE1F-45EF-8E00-9D0B7C98956C/Documents/ccc/image/1446625127.png
```

I download the device container and the image did exist.
What's wrong?

Comment: How do you get the fileURL?

Comment: Create the path dynamically, don't save the whole path instead save the relative path

Comment: why will the path be dynamic?

Comment: Read : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2406/_index.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25884382/ios-8-bundle-path-changes

Comment: Hi. Image which you are trying to fetch is stored in your apps storage?

Answer (score 1):

It's failed to retrieve your file. Use `-dataWithContentsOfFile:options:error:` to find why it is failed.

```
NSError* error = nil;
NSString *path = dict[@"fileURL"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path options: 0 error: &error];

if (data == nil)
{
   NSLog(@"Failed to read file, error %@", error);
}
else
{
    // parse the value
}
```

Comment: the reason is that this path was different from the path which I saved,so there was no file exist in the old path.

Comment: in device/Simutaor if you run once it every time chances the path

Comment: save the related path dont save whole path

Comment: The path is determined on installation. Each time you run your app in the simulator/device, it will be removed and reinstalled. Hence the differernt path. So you don't need to worry about this.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I'm still a little confused. Does it mean that we cannot reload image from the path we previously saved to a database while using the Xcode simulator? I'm also getting "null" data when using "NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: photo1Path];".

Answer (score 0):

I thing you should need to use `[NSFileManager defaultManager]` to store and fetch the image in your application storage instead of writing static path.

Static path is ok withing the simulator but in the real environment you should need to have the actual path. So `[NSFileManager defaultManager]` will help you.

```
if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filepath)
{
   NSData *data = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:filepath];
}
else
{
   NSLog(@"File not exits");
}
```

In `filepath` you need to pass only your folder and file name. not  full path like yours.

IE.

```
filepath = "Documents/ccc/image/1446625127.png";
```

**NOTE:**
This is not a actual answer. This will help you to manage the image into your application storage.